# Editing Floodlight tag to grab form data from the page

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am trying to write some Javascript to amend a Floodlight tag so that it grabs form data from the page and populates a custom variable. My initial thought was to set a variable x lets say and call the document.getElementsByName('...') and reference that variable in the custom variable field i.e. u25=' + x + '. Am I on the right path?

Here is how it looks on the page:

```
<select name="maincontent_0$ddlBikes" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'maincontent_0$ddlBikes\',\'\')', 0)" id="maincontent_0_ddlBikes">
<option value="-1">Which bike would you like to test ride</option>
<optgroup label="Adventure &amp; Touring"><option value="{0E862AD4-9ACB-48F3-BA32-8E68FA2A6858}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger 800 XC</option>
<option value="{51E95170-AACE-4355-8051-24BF4134791F}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger 800 XCA</option>
<option value="{A356E71C-74B0-4566-AAE0-AB879FFFF9C7}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger 800 XCX</option>
<option value="{93798161-E8EC-4FDF-86E7-441EA96A2723}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger 800 XCX low</option>
<option value="{828183FB-2151-489B-82B9-0557EC672244}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger 800 XR</option>
<option value="{4F471C5F-0CA1-4882-8929-6F0B3858F2CB}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger 800 XRT</option>
<option value="{38601676-1641-4B7D-A027-427F21D30961}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger 800 XRX</option>
<option value="{DC926BAA-F718-48AB-B38C-5D56790D5576}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger 800 XRX low</option>
<option value="{68F97139-3FBF-419E-A437-14BD97665EB1}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger Explorer XC</option>
<option value="{CCD93100-E7B2-42CA-9571-F75E0AE7FE7B}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger Explorer XCA</option>
<option value="{CA56B24F-8420-4CC5-B827-567F658654C1}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger Explorer XCx</option>
<option value="{213D8CF5-EFE5-4510-A7E1-1150EFD07A3C}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger Explorer XCx low</option>
<option value="{E7DEFBEA-BF02-46AB-AF3C-7028965FDB44}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger Explorer XR</option>
<option value="{C69673AC-EAD9-49EF-8A19-86E598FFCFE4}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger Explorer XRT</option>
<option value="{62134AB5-465D-4E88-A805-FC17416C78F9}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger Explorer XRx</option>
<option value="{3E12B52E-B441-4130-8002-F1C62EB1C731}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger Explorer XRx low</option>
<option selected="selected" value="{C357BDB9-FB24-4B73-B609-827A9DDA490F}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Tiger Sport</option>
<option value="{95ABB7BC-E142-446B-9861-34A18AE37195}" group="Adventure &amp; Touring">Trophy SE</option>
```

The Floodlight tag is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var axel = Math.random() + "";
 var a = axel * 10000000000000;

 document.write('<iframe src="https://2712390.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=2712390;type=test;cat=url_r000;u25=[URL];dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;ord=' + a + '?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0" style="display:none"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the custom HTML for the floodlight tag and especially not document.write. The only reason the tag uses javascript in the first place is to create a random number as cachebuster, and GTM has a "random" variable that you could use instead and make this pure HTML.

However it is far better to use the [tag template for floodlight tags](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107168?hl=en) and populate the custom variable fields with values from a GTM variable (either a DOM selector or a custom script - I assume you want to get the selected option from your dropdown).